# JavaFX addRow font size for 'Label'

Tags: javafx, fonts, label

How can I set the font size for 'Label' in the following piece of code

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

GridPane root = new GridPane();
root.addRow(0, new Label("winSpeed: "+pressure));
root.addRow(1, new Label("pressure : "+pressure));  
.
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
stage.setTitle("Weather");
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Either: 1. Keep a reference to the label and call `setFont(...)`, or 2. attach an external CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You could either create the label and change the font directly:

```
Label label = new Label("Pressure" + pressure);
label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 30));
root.addRow(0, label);
```

Or you could also use CSS:

```
.label{
    -fx-font: Times New Roman;
    -fx-font-size:  200;
}
```

and Add the Stylesheet to your Scene:

```
scene.getStylesheets().addAll(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("scene.css")).toExternalForm());
```